# wireless router/modem stops working after some minutes when enabling WEP encryption

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, wep

Ive had it with various router/modems, the last one was "Sitecom wireless modem router 300N"
For example, I switch on the router, it works fine for several minutes, and then the connection drops on every notebook computer.

One fix that works is switching the wireless to WPA or better yet WPA2, but often enough the PC's are too old to handle it and will only work with WEP.

It's definitely not someone hacking in, as I experienced the problem right after setting up the router.

The timing for the disconnects is also very exact, in some routers its 10min's, in others it's 5.

Until now I've been assuming that it's some built in function in the router that I am unaware of.

Also I noticed that disabling encryption on the wireless gets the internet back up and running.

How can encrypted WEP disconnect a router anyway??

Comment: Just running through the checklist, but the firmware for the router is up to date? Did you try both WEP modes (40 and 128 bit)?

Comment: haven't tried both, only used the 128 bit, what difference does it make?